# What's the best way to use an array in node.js express 4 and mysql?

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, express

I have a problem when i try to insert values of array into database, this array is populated from multi checkbox in client side, look like this:

```
<div class="checkbox col-md-10">
           <% if(data.length){
                  for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++) { %>
                        <br/>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="tours_multi" value="<%= data[i].idtour %>"><%=data[i].nombre%></label>
                   <%}%>
            <%}%>
</div><!--that's work good-->
```

into the server side look like this:

```
 var datos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
var idtours = [datos.tours_multi];
var idreserva = datos.idreserva;
idtours.forEach(function (tours) {
                                connection.query("INSERT INTO `tours`.`reservacion` (`idtour`, `idreserva`) VALUES ('"+tours+"', '"+idreserva+"')",function(err){
                                    if(err){
                                        connection.rollback(function(){
                                            throw err;
                                            return fn(err);
                                        });
                                    }
                                });

connection.commit(function(err){
                                if(err){
                                    connection.rollback(function(){
                                        throw err;
                                        return fn(err);
                                    });
                                }



                            });
```

when i checked one item it's success but when i selected 3 or 4 or more items it's doesn't work.

Comment: What database driver are you using here? **DO NOT** inject arbitrary data into your queries. Use prepared statements whenever possible.

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "--",
    password: "---",
    database: "---",
    port: "---"
});

exports.connection = connection;

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxFTEy90zOKAfjdxLW92VjY1M1F4OWV6elVkVVQwczFFM1NYdHZfZ1dXZUZaQVh1emVRLVE&usp=sharing          see the picture